# having problems with python error handlers

Tags: python

hello I am pretty new into python , but I am trying to handle errors, however when I try to `ctrl + C or L` I got `input > ^Cerror` which it should be only display `error` and not `^C or ^L` how can I fix this ?

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("error")

except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Comment: try `print("\r")` first

Comment: and `print("error" + " "*30)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can back up and overwrite it, but you can't "fix" it.  That character comes from the keyboard echo of the symbiont terminal: your `stdin` processor is set to echo (print to screen) whatever is typed.  That `^C` couplet is printed by this I/O processing before your program gets to handle the exception.  Thus, the `\r` option (or a sequence of backspaces, `\b`) is likely your best remedy.

```
import sys 

try:
    while True:
        string = input("Show me something")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\b\b  error")

except Exception as e:
    raise e
```

Output, with CTRL-C at keyboard:

```
Show me something  error
```

If you want to wipe out the entire input line, use `\r` instead:

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
print("\rerror", " "*80)
```

Output:

```
Show me something   -- this line appears until I hit CTRL-C.  Replaced by
error
```